# Why can endpoints not be local extremum after this definition?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, definition

The definition my textbook gives on local extremum is that it's an $f(a)$ so that $f(a) \geq f(x)$ for a local maximum and $f(a) \leq f(x)$ for a local minimum for $x \in N(a)$ and $x \in D_f$ where $N(a)$ denotes the neighborhood of a.

> Using this definition, why can endpoint can not be a local extremum?

As an example, $f$ is defined on $[-4, 5]$. Say $f$ has a global maximum at $-4$.

We pick $N(-4) = (-5, -3)$, now for $x \in N(-4) \text{ } \cap \text{ } x \in D_f = [-4, 5]$, it must hold that $f(-4) \geq f(x)$.
We don't need to worry about $x$ being less than $-4$ because it needs to be both in the interval and domain.

> So does $N(a)$ also have to be a subinterval of $D_f$? That condition would make picking the above $N(-4)$ invalid.

Comment: The neighborhoods you want are neighborhoods that are subsets of the domain.

Comment: @EthanBolker Oh, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You can answer your own question and accept the answer, or delete it. But don't just leave it attracting attention on the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @EthanBolker for answering this question in the comments!

> So does $N(a)$ also have to be a subinterval of $D_f$? That condition would make picking the above $N(−4)$ invalid.

This is true and picking $N(-4) = (-5, 3)$ is invalid, there is no way to pick a neighborhood that is a subset of the domain and includes $-4$, since a neighborhood has to go in both directions and $-4$ is already the left bound of $D_f$. Thus $f(-4)$ is not a local maximum of $f$ and generally, endpoints can't be local extremum.